# Software and scanner for scanning photographic slides?

Tags: 10.10, software-recommendation, hardware, usb

I am searching for software and hardware for scanning slides to import to digitize my old pictures..

I have already a scanner working in Windows, but I would like to scan them directly in Ubuntu.

- Ubuntu 10.10
- Scanner: :ZOLID
- lsusb output: OmniVision Technologies, Inc. VEHO Filmscanner

Comment: Could you try if `digikam` finds your scanner? You may need to install it `sudo apt-get install digikam` (or from software center).

Answer (score 4):

I've tested several scanner programs in Ubuntu and I think "**gscan2pdf**" is the best.

You can scan with ADF scanners (feeds the photos/sheets automatically), batch crop pages, set brighness/contrast (and more) before scanning (saves a lot of time), edit the pictures in GIMP or other external program, do OCR on text and more.

You can install it using the Ubuntu Program Central (or compile it from source: http://gscan2pdf.sourceforge.net/ )

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't address the main question of scanning slides.  I have the same problem.  The back-light never activates.

Answer (score 3):

For scanning slides and negatives, the best I've found is VueScan from Ed Hamrick of Hamrick.com. It's available for Linux, Windows, and Mac and supports MANY scanners with it's own drivers. Try the trial version to see if it works with your scanner (it puts watermarks on the scans, but at least you can see if it'll work for you).

Not Free (in either sense), but a substantially better value and better service than you get from most paid-for software.

Answer (score 2):

I have just received a similar (branded OTEK Filmscanner FS500-2) scanner and also had trouble getting it to work (Windows 8 had no support for it but no surprises there). Vuescan also unfortunately didn't recognise it either. I did however manage to get it to work under Ubuntu 13.04 although it failed under 12.04.

lsusb gives me:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05a9:1550 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. VEHO Filmscanner
```

and I found that Cheese will capture photos from it as looking at syslog it appears to be treated as a USB Camera

```
 kernel: [  251.108071] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
 kernel: [  251.241541] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05a9, idProduct=1550
 kernel: [  251.241546] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
 kernel: [  251.241549] usb 1-4: Product: USB Camera
 kernel: [  251.241552] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: FW-07.07.25
 prometheus mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4"
 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
 kernel: [  251.306084] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
 kernel: [  251.325134] gspca_main: v2.14.0 registered
 kernel: [  251.337586] gspca_main: ov534_9-2.14.0 probing 05a9:1550
 kernel: [  253.184436] usbcore: registered new interface driver ov534_9
 colord: Device added: sysfs-FW-07.07.25-USB_Camera
```

You can install cheese by:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

But I am now looking for something that feels a little less 'cheesy' for scanning all those old family negatives (and the one filter that cheese seems to be missing is 'negative' so I can see what the photos actually look like while scanning them.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/186003/anything-better-than-cheese-for-video-capture has helped me in my search for a slightly more full features video capture solution (guvcview)

Answer (score 0):

You should go to Applications -> Graphics -> Simple Scan.

Comment: Simple Scan does not recognize my scanner, same as xsane, that's why I also asked for hardware

Comment: so you are looking for scanners that work in ubuntu?

Comment: simple-scan uses sane as backend, so if it doesn't work in xsane, it won't work in simple-scan.

Comment: yes a photo slide scanner for ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I use an Epson Perfection V300 Photo to scan photo's, slides and documents. I downloaded the drivers from http://avasys.jp/hp/page000001300/hpg000001277.htm. After installing the software a new entry ImageScan! for Linux is created in the menu. You can scan only 1 slide at a time (although the paceholder has storage for 4 slides). I perform postprocessing (clipping, adjust contrast, remove scratches and artefacts) by means of Gimp (or Picasa).

Answer (score 0):

As for the hardware part of the question, my HP 3 in 1 scanner works perfectly with simple scan without any need for drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can see images properly using `cheese` if you install `xcalib` and run the terminal command

```
xcalib -i -a
```

which inverts your display colours. Run it again to put things back to normal.

`cheese` works ok but seems to destructively compress images it saves. I've found that `webcamoid` does a better job. Once you have saved the negative image, you use GIMP and the menu command *['Colors' (sic), 'Invert']* to fix colours.

You will likely have to process it further. *['Colors'; 'Auto'; 'White balance']* works ok if you're lazy, but you can do a better job taking more time.

Answer (score 0):

`guvcview` worked for me, under ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please be specific when mentioning versions especially the version of the distro you are referencing to. There are always two Ubuntu versions a year, so 18 is not clear enough.Apart from that the question is nine years old and referencing Ubuntu 10.10, so your answer might not be as helpful as it was intended.

Comment: @neun24 I will fix the version.