# Is there a way to make video the default in cheese?

Tags: video, webcam, dconf, cheese

I am trying to make it easier for my kid to make videos, she can never remember to set the recording mode to video, so I would like to make it the default.
I have looked at the options in `dconf-editor` but I do not see an option to change the default setting to video. Is there anything else I can do?

I am using Ubuntu Mate, 15.10

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/186003/anything-better-than-cheese-for-video-capture

Comment: guvcview seems robust, but from the perspective of a 5 year old, its quite complex. Maybe someday we can leverage that. But I'm trying to have a set up she can do all by herself, with 100% success.