# Skype doesn't recognise v4l2loopback + gstreamer

Tags: video, skype, webcam, obs-studio, v4l

I recently bought a full HD webcam and I'm running into some troubles using it on Ubuntu 19.10. The main issue is that I get very low fps (about 5-7) unless I run the webcam on relatively low resolutions.

I first tried using guvcview after reading [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/186003/720274), but I was still having low fps issues for some reason, and following the steps in [this video](https://youtu.be/iuic3po8kvQ) didn't help (even trying to find my own ideal exposure).

I then decided to use OBS which solved the fps issue on my computer, but then when I tried to use the magic OBS was doing for Skype it didn't work... I followed the steps to install [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback#install) and [obs-v4l2sink](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink#build), updated the [solution to get Skype to recognise the virtual device](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki/Skype) for the current version of gstreamer and so ended up with this code to start the video signal (`/dev/video2` is the device created by `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`):

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

However Skype still doesn't recognise my device... I don't really know anything about gstreamer or anything really so it is quite possible I made a stupid mistake, would really appreciate if someone could point it out! I'm also open to any solutions to the general problem of "getting my webcam to have a good fps" :)

Small extra detail: VLC is fine with the virtual device before the gstreamer command, and after the gstreamer command VLC shows me some weird flashing multicolour rectangles.

Comment: ever solved this?