# Cheese Resolution low

Tags: display-resolution, webcam, scanner

The only application I have found which recognises my Maginon FS500 slide/35mm scanner is Cheese. The resolution is only 592x392 though, this works out at about 1/4Mp whereas the scanner claims 5Mp. How can I sort this out, is there a good Cheese forum? If I can't fix Cheese, what is it doing that is right that enables it to find the scanner, which the other software doesn't?

Edit: None of the scanner software I have tried work with it, it isn't a "Sane" device and it isn't really a "Scanner" it doesn't scan! It takes a photo.
There are quality settings in Cheese, but the value shown is unchangeable.

Comment: Scanners should work with usual scanning software tools, not Cheese. Cheese if for webcams. Related but old: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23991/software-and-scanner-for-scanning-photographic-slides . Some software mentioned may not be available today, some other better and newer may exist. Exactly what other softwares have you tried?

Comment: Did you check the prefs for Cheese. You cant set the resolution there. Does `Simple Scan` find the slide scanner?